# How to find the latest SQL statements within the database?

Tags: oracle, monitoring

I like to get the latest executed statements within my database, along with performance indicators.

As such, I like to know, which SQL statements were most CPU/DISK intensive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the SQL to do the job. Open for trial.

Step 1: Determine the installatin IDs & user IDs.

```
SELECT inst_id,sid FROM gv$session WHERE username='<ENTER-USERNAME>';
```

Step 2:

```
SELECT 
      s.sid
     ,s.CLIENT_INFO
     ,s.MACHINE
     ,s.PROGRAM
     ,s.TYPE
     ,s.logon_time
     ,s.osuser
     ,sq.sorts
     ,sq.DISK_READS
     ,sq.BUFFER_GETS
     ,sq.ROWS_PROCESSED
     ,sq.SQLTYPE
     ,sq.SQL_TEXT
 FROM gv$session s    
    , gv$sql sq
WHERE s.SQL_HASH_VALUE = sq.HASH_VALUE
  AND s.inst_id = :inst_id -- replace with instID from above
  AND s.sid = :sid -- replace with ID from above
  AND sq.inst_id = s.inst_id
```

There might be multiple Ids & instance Ids returned. So it's up to a users' choice on how to use this data in a web interface etc.

Comment: Just small note: Oracle supports (no idea from which version) `in` operator with tuples, so from example above `... AND (s.inst_id, s.sid) in ( (:id1, :sid1), (:id2, :sid2), ... )`

Comment: 'inst_id' stands for the instance Id, itdoes not meaninstallation id.

Answer (score 13):

Oracles Enterprise Monitor console shows a whole wealth of information about which SQL queries are taking the max CPU, bottlenecks, top activity in the database, blocking SQLs et al.

For a historical approach, you can use Oracle's [AWR](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/AutomaticWorkloadRepository10g.php) reports to pin point areas concerning you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity - AWR is a tool available to all Oracle licenses & could I use it via command line only?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it - from what I know, AWR requires a separate licensing - the [Oracle Tuning & Diagnostic Pack](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/options.htm#CIHFIHFG). I prefer to use AWR from the Enterprise Manager console - I've been blessed with the privilege(!) to utilize the Enterprise Manager console. I also [found that](http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/1506-Real-Time-SQL-Monitoring-in-SQL-Developer.html) you can use SQL Developer to monitor SQLs, but that requires the above licensing

Comment: Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) is very nice.  We can monitor our database health in near real-time with auto-refreshed graphs.  We've got a big monitor hanging on a wall showing OEM for our primary databases 24x7 and its hugely beneficial in identifying problems as they occur.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `V$SQL`, there are several interesting columns `RUNTIME_MEM, EXECUTIONS, DISK_READS, SORTS, ELAPSED_TIME, SQL_FULLTEXT` etc.

This would give you top 10 statements by disk read (note - this is cumulative for all executions):

```
select sql_id,child_number from
(
select sql_id,child_number from v$sql
order by disk_reads desc
)
where rownum<11
```

If the statement is still in `V$SQL_PLAN` you can get an actual explain plan for the query:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('sql_id',child_number));
```

I also like to use `V$SQL_PLAN` as it contains good info. If your `statistics_level=ALL` you can use `V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS`.

Answer (score 2):

For recent SQL:

```
select * from v$sql
```

For history:

```
select * from dba_hist_sqltext
```